# Where can I find sample Delphi code or component for accessing exchange/outlook contacts and appointments?

Tags: delphi

I need Delphi code or component for accessing exchange/outlook contacts and appointments? I probably need to use Extended MAPI. This is for a proof of concept so I'm not ready to shell out big bucks at the moment. Any hints, links, experiences??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look this

Create an appointment in MS Outlook

http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0128.htm

Contact list in MS Outlook

http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0145.htm

Answer (score 2):

Look at [EasyMAPI](http://www.rapware.nl/prod_easymapi_page1.asp?SubMenu=EasyMAPI) from [Rapware](http://www.rapware.nl/).

Not free, but well worth the price.  I used this a couple of years ago.  The author was really helpful and open to adding new functionality.

Answer (score 1):

at our company we used the converted Extended mapi C/C++ headers (to delphi) and examples from here http://www.imibo.com/imidev/delphi/les/index.html. it doesn't cost that much at least i think so.

We used it to create a sync service that would synchronized tasks, contacts and appointments from our own agenda which was build before i worked at the company with exchange directly.

The plus side is you can use MSDN since basically everything is the same as what's written there and you have full control but it's rather "low level"

I'm not really certain if it is that what you need, but you don't really need outlook to be installed to access the messages then (on exchange). If you just need outlook you could try OLE or some of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if TurboPower OfficePartner supports the features you're looking for, but it's free (as in open source) and might be worth a look:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpofficepartner/