# How can I find the details of Outlook data in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, outlook, ole

I found the following code [here](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0145.htm). It was referred to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/761843/2920050) here on StackOverflow.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  olFolderContacts = $0000000A;
var
  Outlook, NameSpace, Contacts, Contact: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  NameSpace := Outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
  Contacts := NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts);

  for i := 1 to Contacts.Items.Count do
  begin
    Contact := Contacts.Items.Item(i);
    {now you can read any property of contact. For example, full name and
     email address}
    ShowMessage(Contact.FullName + ' <' + Contact.Email1Address + '>'); 
  end;

  Outlook := UnAssigned;
end;
```

The [Scalabium link](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0145.htm) lists the properties for the `Contact` object, presumably including `FullName` and `Email1Address`. However, when I run the code I get errors that neither exists. Is my way to access a contact correct? And how do I know which properties a contact has, once I've retrieved it?

**update**
I found the cause for the error, but not a solution yet. The first contact in the list appears to be a **contact group**, and for those `FullName` and `Email1Address` (among other properties don't exist). The code works for ordinary contacts. But I don't know how to tell contact groups from ordinary contacts. I tried a `try`..`except`, but no exception seems to be generated.

I also tried `OutlookSpy` as suggested by *whosrdaddy*, but I couldn't find a property like `IsGroup` or something like that.

Comment: [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) is your friend :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: As a side note, cache the Items collection before entering the loop instead of using multiple dot notation (Contacts.Items.Item(i)) inside the loop - each "." returns a brand new COM object.

Comment: @Dmitry: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I could write it shorter: Contacts.Items(i), is that what you mean? Otherwise feel free to improve the code in the question.

Comment: No, I mean you need to store the value of  Contacts.Items in a variable before entering the loop (vItems := Contacts.Items), then use that variable inside the loop (vItems.Item(i)) instead of calling  Contacts.Items on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the Contact's class, like this:

```
const  
  olDistributionList = 69;

....

  Contact := ContactsRoot.Items(I);
  if (Contact.class = olDistributionList) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(String(Contact) + ' is a contact group')
  else
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Contact.LastName + ' <' + Contact.Email1Address + '>');
```

The string typecast is necessary because the `+` operator to concatenate strings doesn't work on Contact as an OleVariant.

Comment: Instead of String(Contact) use Contact.DLName. You also need (just a sanity check) to verify that Contact.Class = 40 (olContact) before assuming the item is a contact.